# Draw rounded image with white background using Picasso

Tags: android, picasso

I have some images with white background and some with transparent backgrounds. When creating a rounded image of them I want all of them to have the white background so basically I want to replace the transparent pixels of the images with white pixels.

Is there any way of achieving this without resorting to replacing one by one pixel? This is the transformation I use for creating the rounded images:

```
package com.mobilefootie.util;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.BitmapShader;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.Shader;

public class RoundedTransformation implements com.squareup.picasso.Transformation {

public RoundedTransformation() {

}

@Override
public Bitmap transform(final Bitmap source) {
    int size = Math.min(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight());

    int x = (source.getWidth() - size) / 2;
    int y = (source.getHeight() - size) / 2;

    Bitmap squaredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, x, y, size, size);          
    if (squaredBitmap != source) {
        source.recycle();
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(size, size, source.getConfig());

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

    Paint paint = new Paint();

    BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(squaredBitmap, BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP, BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP);
    paint.setShader(shader);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);

    float r = size/2f;
    canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r, paint);

    squaredBitmap.recycle();
    return bitmap;

}

@Override
public String key() {
    return "rounded";
}
}
```

Comment: Hey how do you apply this to an image in picasso... currently I load an image (which is a string url from my server) like so Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(photoUrl).resize(100, 100).into(profilePicture);

Comment: Picasso.with(getActivity())
     .load(url)     
     .transform(new RoundedTransformation())
     .into(imageView);

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to set a `ColorFilter` for you `Paint` (I applied GREEN for better visualization):

```
BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(squaredBitmap, BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP, BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP);
paint.setShader(shader);
paint.setAntiAlias(true);

PorterDuff.Mode mMode = PorterDuff.Mode.OVERLAY;
paint.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.GREEN, mMode));
```

Comment: That worked 90%. If you change your answer to PorterDuff.Mode mMode = PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OVER; then it works like magic. Thanks! :-)

Comment: Thank you! with @ Christer Nordvik's improvement it works perfectly

Comment: excellent code. I made it work too. How compatible is it? (Android versions under 4.1, different screen sizes, etc)